# How to run sharepoint content organizer with JSOM?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2016, sharepoint-jsom

In `SharePoint` I added a shortcut-function to change the content types of selected elements in a list. This already works pretty well. But when I use it in the drop off library, I want the content organizer rule immediately executed - but nothing happens. After selecting a file and saving its properties (without changing anything) the content organizer rule is triggered and does its job.

Is it possible to trigger the rule manually by using `JSOM`?

Comment: Is this for a single document being uploaded or multiple? As far as I know it runs the Content Organizer Rule immediately for single documents being uploaded but on a timer for multiple documents.

Comment: I upload multiple documents. Then I change the ContentType with JSOM to that one that is configured in the rule. So, isn't there any possibility to force the execution of the rule before the timer expires?